# How can I bind this.save to a backbone.js model change event?

Tags: backbone.js

I want my model to save to the server every time it changes.

I have tried:

```
initialize: function() {
    this.bind('change', this.save());
},
```

I'm new to Backbone so I'm willing to believe there is a better way to achieve this. Basically I want avoid calling model.save at other points in my code by just automatically saving to the server every time the model changes.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you are calling this.save immediately instead of passing it through as a callback function.remove the parenthesis on `this.save`:

```
initialize: function() {
    this.bind('change', this.save);
},
```

and your model's `this.save` method will be passed in as a function reference, allowing it to be called when the model changes.

Answer (score 21):

Careful with using this.save directly:

```
this.bind('change', this.save);
```

will cause the changed attributes sent with the change event to be passed in to the save method, which will cause a second 'change' event to be fired, and so it will be saved twice.

Instead use:

```
this.bind('change', function(){ this.save(); });
```